# Service file not playing video

Tags: python, services

I have written a Python script that receives an online link from the server and downloads it and plays it simultaneously. After that, it plays it from the device unless it receives a new video link.

I have written a service file that runs this code once the device boots.

**device.service file**

```
    [Unit]
    Description=My device boot script service
    After=multi-user.target

    [Service]
    Type=idle
    User=root
    Environment=DISPLAY=:0
    Restart=on-failure
    ExecStart=/root/Video_project/start.sh 

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**start.sh script**

```
#!/bin/bash
#exec 1> >(logger -s -t $(basename $0)) 2>&1
python /root/Video_project/main.py
```

**Python function to play video**

I have these 3 functions running which displays the image and the video

```
def image_func():
    img_link = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/o4IVan08VvI/maxresdefault.jpg"
    img_cmd = "feh -F %s"%(img_link)
    os.system(img_cmd)

def play_video_from_server(link):
    print("Playing video from server")
    cmd = "mplayer -fs ffmpeg://%s" %(link)    #link is read from JSON file
    os.system(cmd)

def play_video_from_device(link_ID):
    print("Playing video from Device")
    cmd = "mplayer -fs %s.mp4" %(link_ID)    #link_ID .mp4 is the name of the downloaded video
    os.system(cmd)
```

The video player and image viewer never open in the front screen. How should I make it run to view the image and video?